# How to plot linear trend line plotted for given values?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to understand how the linear trend line is drawn. I tried the linear column trend line in excel sheet. For the points $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$ It draws a line it touches all the points.

If I change the points to $(12,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$ like this , it's not touching all the points exactly. the Line goes in these points approximately $(4.8, 6,6.2,6.4,6.8,7.2,7.8,8,8.2)$ Something like this.

I want to know how the linear trend line is drawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is least squares, please see here for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares

Moreover, in Excel, when you `Add Trendline...` you can choose to display the trendline's equation on the chart, which helps to get additional insights. In addition, Excel supports multiple trendline types - linear, exponential, logarithmic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly a "least-squares" fit. Details of how to calculate least squares fit lines are given on this page: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics). See especially the section entitled "motivational example".